# How do I get Elasticsearch to highlight a partial word from a search_as_you_type field?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-7

I'm having trouble setting up a search_as_you_type field with highlighting following the guide here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/search-as-you-type.html

I'll leave a series of commands to reproduce what I'm seeing. Hopefully somebody can weigh in on what I'm missing :)

1. create mapping

```
PUT /test_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "plain_text": {
        "type": "search_as_you_type",
        "index_options": "offsets",
        "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. insert document

```
POST /test_index/_doc
{
  "plain_text": "This is some random text"
}
```

3. search for document

```
GET /snippets_test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "rand",
      "type": "bool_prefix",
      "fields": [
        "plain_text",
        "plain_text._2gram",
        "plain_text._3gram",
        "plain_text._index_prefix"
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight" : {
    "fields" : [
      {
        "plain_text": {
          "number_of_fragments": 1,
          "no_match_size": 100
        } 
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

4. response

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "rLZkjm8BDC17cLikXRbY",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "plain_text" : "This is some random text"
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "plain_text" : [
            "This is some random text"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The response I get back does not have the highlighting I expect 
Idealy the highlight is: `This is some <em>ran</em>dom text`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to achieve highlighting of n-grams (chars) you'll need:

- a custom ngram tokenizer. By default the maximum difference between `min_gram` and `max_gram` is 1, so in my example highlighting will work only for the search terms with length 3 or 4. You can change this and creating more n-grams by setting a higher value for `index.max_ngram_diff` .
- a custom analyzer based on the custom tokenizer
- in mapping add "plain_text.highlight" field

Here's the configuration:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "partial_words" : {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "ngrams",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "ngrams": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 4
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "plain_text": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "shingles": { 
            "type": "search_as_you_type"
          },
          "ngrams": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "partial_words",
            "search_analyzer": "standard",
            "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "rand",
      "type": "bool_prefix",
      "fields": [
        "plain_text.shingles",
        "plain_text.shingles._2gram",
        "plain_text.shingles._3gram",
        "plain_text.shingles._index_prefix",
        "plain_text.ngrams"
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight" : {
    "fields" : [
      {
        "plain_text.ngrams": { } 
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and the result:

```
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "FkHLVHABd_SGa-E-2FKI",
            "_score": 2,
            "_source": {
                "plain_text": "This is some random text"
            },
            "highlight": {
                "plain_text.ngrams": [
                    "This is some <em>rand</em>om text"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
```

Note: in some cases, this config might be expensive for memory usage and storage.

Comment: I had moved from 'search_as_you_type' to an ngram analyzer, but this answer still applies to me! I still needed to move my ngram from the filter to the tokenizer. Thanks :)

Comment: With the query "ran" this solution produces the highlight: "This is some <em>ran</em><em>d</em>om text" which ends up highlighting "rand" instead of highlighting just "ran".

Comment: @catalin-m Hey one query here. For eg: I have a query like 'good developer' and i have some indexes like 'developer and tester', 'not only developer', 'good developer', 'good tester'. Then when i query with search as you type, i am getting all the indexs which includes developer. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @James Could you please share how you moved from 'search_as_you_type' to an ngram analyzer?

Comment: @Vishnu happy to take a look at your problem, but the comment section here isn't the best place. It's very hard for me to reproduce your issue without more information. My recommendation is for you to write up something the way I did with: mapping/index, document creation and query commands. Then, describe what you see, and why that is not what you expect to see. Basically, try to provide as much information as possible to make the Answer's job easier.